# QToolButton: change menu position

Tags: qt

When using menu with `QToolButton` menu is shown right under the button. Is there a way to display menu in the left/right of the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position is hard-coded in the function `void QToolButtonPrivate::popupTimerDone()` in *[Qt install directory]/src/gui/widgets/qtoolbutton.cpp*. It seems pretty hard to override that, unless you implement your own popup menu from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was answered a while ago, but I wanted to add a new answer to this question since the accepted answer is no longer valid.  It is actually quite easy to change the menu position on a QToolButton.   You need to subclass QMenu and override the event function.  When there is a show event, just change the position of the menu.

Here is a simple example using PySide:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def event(self,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.move(self.parent().mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0,0))-QtCore.QPoint(0,self.height()))
        return super(MyMenu,self).event(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.setGeometry(100,100,500,500)
    tb = QtGui.QToolButton(w)
    tb.setText("HELLO")
    tb.setGeometry(70,70,40,30)
    m = MyMenu("Menu",tb)
    m.addAction("Exit")
    tb.setMenu(m)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! BTW, you can also use an eventFilter if you don't want (or can't) inherit `QMenu`

Comment: This works quite well. You may want to add a check that `self.parent()` is indeed a `QWidget` before calling the move though, because it is not at all guaranteed that it is in the general case. If it isn't, calling `mapToGlobal()` will cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the menu when the menu showing. This is the trick.

```
QMenu* menu = new Menu();
somePushButton->setMenu(menu);
menu->installEventFilter(this);
 
bool myWidget::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Show && obj == somePushButton->menu())
    {
        QPoint pos = calculateposition
        somePushButton->menu()->move(pos);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please check this [thread](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49023-QPushButton-with-menu-gt-How-to-set-position-of-the-menu).