# Make QToolButton show menu on top in Qt 5.9

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5.9

Is there a way for a [QToolButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html) to display its associated [QMenu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html) on top of it instead of below?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922556/4613742) answer which pleased me but it's in Python and I don't really know how to port it properly.

I also took a look at the [source code for QMenu](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.10/src/widgets/widgets/qmenu.cpp#L2937) but it's quite overwhelming so I don't really know how to tackle this issue.

There also is a little arrow on the button showing that it'll pop down.
[image: Here is the situation]

This is the very bottom of my window so I'd like it to pop up in case it becomes too big to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using an event filter:

```
QMenu* yourMenu;
yourButton->setMenu(yourMenu);
yourMenu->installEventFilter(this);

bool yourClass::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Show && obj == yourButton->menu())
    {
        QPoint pos = /*the position expected*/;
        yourButton->menu()->move(pos);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To remove the little arrow, add this to your stylesheet:

```
QToolButton::menu-indicator{
    image: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Alright, I didn't know this thing, I'll give it a shot. While you're here, is there a way to make the little arrow point upwards on the button? And if it's not possible, can I just remove it completely?

Comment: @Telokis Yes, added the removal of the arrow :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's enough for me! :)